# ping across broadcast domains

Tags: networking, ping, switch

(non native english poster)

As I was trying to test the way ARP resolves the IP addresses on the layer 2, I have set up a host (H1) with a fix IP having the following address `inet 192.168.0.123/16 brd 192.168.255.255` and another host (H2) having `inet 192.168.0.155/24 brd 192.168.0.255` as address. H1 and H2 are both wired to the same switch.

I was expecting not to be able to ping H1 from H2 as they belong to different subnets or broadcast domains, but ping worked. I flushed the ARP tables on H2, same result.

I also reset the switch to empty its ARP table, but I still could ping across two different broadcast domains.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have gateways setup to route the traffic?

Comment: Yes. The default route on both hosts point to the same gateway. I would have thought that ARP packets (L2) were not routed.

Comment: because of the 16 bit mask H1 will think it is on the same network as H2. But from H2's perspective H1 is NOT on the same network and will get routed through the gateway. ARP does not come into play until the packet reaches the destination network.

Comment: Correct. They are routed. See my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

First, subnet (or IP network) is not generally the same as a [Broadcast domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain). A Broadcast domain deals with OSI Layer 2 concepts, and the propagation of frames, not packets.

Second, Ping uses the ICMP protocol, which occurs at OSI layer 3, so pings can cross routers to remote networks. It is not suprising that you can ping a device on a another network.

ARP and PING have essentially nothing to do with each other. your local machine does not need to perform an ARP request to find a remote station, because it just sends an IP datagram to the default gateway (which it does look up via ARP), and lets the router work out the rest.

Comment: I disconnected the link with the router and, indeed the ICPM packets get routed which does make sense as ping uses a L3 protocol. So, I crafted pure ARP packets using nping to stay at L2 (with the router disconnected) and the ARP requests were also received on the other host. After a second though, I think I remember that these packets are broadcasted on 255.255.255.255, and not only on the subnet broadcast address 192.0.168.0.255. That makes that all hosts connected to a switch with whatever ip/mask they might have will receive the ARP packet. Can you confirm?

Comment: well, that actually is kind of a grey area. the RFCs on IP do state that an IP broadcast to 255.255.255.255 would hit all hosts on all networks, but most router vendors have realized that that would be disruptive and have instead reframe these packets with a destination mac of FFFFFFFFFFFF (a so-called Local Broadcast). That frame will go out every switch port in the Broadcast Domain. As such, behavior varies from vendor to vendor. Now a quick question, are all these hosts sharing a switch fabric (a VLAN scehario)?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what a switch fabric is, but no vlan here. It's a dumb switch (albeit a Linksys when it still was Cisco). No tagging if that is what you mean.

Comment: well, ARP operates at a very low level so you can use VLANs to allow devices on the same switch or set of connected switches (this is called a switch fabric) to be in different IP networks. in such a scenario, the PCs might be in different IP networks (which is only partially true in your case; see @MariusMatutiae's answer) but have an ARP table that contains the MAC address of both endpoints. the devices would effectively be on the same network at layer 1 and 2, but different networks at layer 3. Most VLAN solutions would have an ARP table per vlan, but that is vendor determined.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see why you are surprised.

> inet 192.168.0.123/16 brd 192.168.255.255
>
> inet 192.168.0.155/24 brd 192.168.0.255

Though the two networks are distinct, H1 is inside H2's network, and H2 is inside H1's network. Hence they **must** be able to communicate.

This trumps the fact that you are confusing OSI model layer-2 (ARP) and layer-3 (ICMP) protocols.  In fact, you state,

> ...I still could ping across two different broadcast domains.

(which is an example of the confusion between layer-2 (broadcast domain) and layer-3 (ping) concepts), but the funny thing is you are **not** pinging **across** anything at all: one of the two IP network **contains** the other one, and H1 and H2 both belong to the common area between the two, so you are actually pinging **inside** both nets.